# Android, reach Button via DialogFragment?

Tags: android, timepicker, android-dialogfragment

What i want: the buttons text is "08:00" now. When click the button it shows a timepicker. The selected time is set to the buttons text. (Alarm app).
i have read some tutorials and questions-answers about this, but haven't find the answers yet. After i press the clock button the app crashes. If i put the onCreateView part in comment it works. it says: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content.

```
public class TimeSet extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private Button clock;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // R.layout.my_layout - that's the layout where your textview is placed
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, container, false);
        clock = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.ora);
        // you can use your textview.
        return view;
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        clock.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hourOfDay).append(":").append(minute));
    }

}
```

Comment: you want to show the dialog fragment when you click on the button?. i guess you have the button in activity

Comment: yes. I have this: android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog" in the xml. It works when the onCreateView is commented, but is does nothing that's why i made this. I'd like to "findViewById" the Button but i am unable to do it in DialogFragment. So I read about this inflater thing but doesn't working.

Comment: show us where you have button the activity code where you invoke the dialogfragment

Comment: in Main.java this code runs when i click the button. 
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimeSet();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

Comment: you want the time choosen back in activity? no need for inflating a layout in dialogfragment then

Comment: This is what i want: When clicks the button it shows a timepicker. The user select the time and the time chosen is showed as the buttons text (alarm app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment

```
When clicks the button it shows a timepicker. The user select the time and the time chosen is showed as the buttons text (alarm app).
```

There is no need to inflate a layout.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Use a Interface as a call back to the activity.

On Button click show the `DialogFragment`. Use a interface. Implement the same in Activity and set the time to button

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    public interface PickTime
    {
        public void returnTime(String value);

    }

    PickTime mCallback;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    mCallback = (PickTime) getActivity();
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
// Do something with the time chosen by the user

    if(mCallback!=null)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(hourOfDay);
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(minute);
        mCallback.returnTime(sb.toString());
    }
}
}
```

In your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements PickTime{

    Button button;
    TimePickerFragment newFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                  newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

               }
            });
    }
    @Override
    public void returnTime(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        button.setText(value);

    }

}
```

Comment: It does not matter. This is just an example i am showing. Make sure you implement the interface and make sure your have button declared as a instance variable. the real deal is the interface here.

Comment: @user3137292 glad to help. this solution can also be used if you want the value from Fragment (not only DialogFragment) to activity.